# Need a "Scicos" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

I've written a question about a Scicos error but there isn't a Scicos TAG and I don't have privileges enough to create a new one. Is it possible to request a new TAG in StackOverflow?

Comment: the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397233

Comment: Jazzinghen, don't forget to link to the question in, euh, question.

Comment: Thank you! I'll remember for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`[status-completed]`**